# org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect

I'm creating a new Elasticsearch connector from kafka and I'm getting this error:
`org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler`

Looks like is the serialization of the topic, but I've test both JsonConverter & AvroConverter in the value and key converter.

Any ideas which is the issue here?

```
{
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
  "connection.url": "es-endpoint",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "topics": "simple.elasticsearch.data",
  "name": "simple-elasticsearch-connector",
  "type.name": "_doc",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "schema.ignore": "true",
  "key.ignore": "true"
 }
```

I was following the examples here: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-elasticsearch-connector-tutorial/

Comment: That isn't the real error. Show the full stacktrace, please

Answer (score 0):

Error is not in full. If you error shows something like this;

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:180)\n\t... 11 more\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message\nCaused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: confluent-schema-registry\n\tat
```

Describe your pod and check the environment variables.

```
kubectl.exe describe pod cp-kafka-connect-12fc858c8b-jj5sx -n namespace
```

to see if a protocol is specified for your schema registry URL;

```
CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL:    confluent-schema-registry:18081
CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL:  confluent-schema-registry:18081
```

If it is something like above, edit your deployment to look like below or redeploy kafka-connect with schema registry with a protocol HTTP or HTTPS.

```
CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL:    http://confluent-schema-registry:18081
CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL:  http://confluent-schema-registry:18081
```